# How to do unsupervised clustering on sentences to find intents

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, clustering, data-mining, chatbot

I am working on chatbot for students.
So, I have chatlogs on conversation between student and tutor, which is on mathematical problems (no labels).
First thing I want to find is intents, such as whether given line is problem description from student , doubt from student or greetings. 
For which I tried with **sentence transformer with math bert** to create embeddings and use **umap** with cosine as metric to do dimensional reduction, and then cluster them using **hdbscan** to find all intents possible, but the results weren't that great.
Also, tried with zero-shot classification with bart, which did not give better results.

Any idea on what could be better approach?